# Extjs tree panel not loading json data

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, extjs4

Hi I am trying to load data for tree panel through json and
I'm referring [this link](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/extjs-build/examples/build/KitchenSink/ext-theme-neptune/#tree-reorder).  tree panel is showing properly except there is no data.

  here is my code 
 **Edit** updated code as Objectone suggested

```
Ext.require([
'Ext.tree.*',
'Ext.data.*',
'Ext.tip.*'
]);

Ext.onReady(function() {

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'treeJson.json'
    },      
    root: {
        expanded: true
    },
    folderSort: true,
    sorters: [{
        property: 'text',
        direction: 'ASC'
    }]
});

var tree = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    store: store,
    renderTo: 'tree-div',
    height: 300,
    width: 250,
    title: 'Files',
    useArrows: true,
    dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        items: [{
            text: 'Expand All',
            handler: function(){
                tree.expandAll();
            }
        }, {
            text: 'Collapse All',
            handler: function(){
                tree.collapseAll();
            }
        }]
    }]
});

console.log(store.getRootNode());
});
```

here is json

```
[
   {
    "text": "To Do",
    "cls": "folder",
    "expanded": true,
    "children": [
        {
            "text": "Go jogging",
            "leaf": true
        },
        {
            "text": "Take a nap",
            "leaf": true
        },
        {
            "text": "Climb Everest",
            "leaf": true
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Firebug is showing no error,
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Give id for JSON as 'src'

Comment: Kishan, I tried to give id for json but it didn't work, now I removed id from root but it is showing only root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you store you are mentioning the root id as src but your json doesn't has the id of src.

In the example link JSON is as below, id is mentioned as "src/fx" where src is the root

```
{text:fx, id:src/fx, cls:folder, qtip:Type: Folder<br />Last Modified: Jul 9, 2013, 3:24 am}
```

To get your stuff working just remove the id from root

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'treeJson.json'
    },      
    root: {
        expanded: true
    },
    folderSort: true,
    sorters: [{
        property: 'text',
        direction: 'ASC'
    }]
});
```

Comment: thank you objectone for your response, I tried your suggestion but it is still not showing any data except root.

Comment: this code is WORKING on my server but NOT on my local machine, seems something is wrong with my URL. +1 for your input :)